# RESideMenu not working for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am using the RESideMenu resource for iPhone/iPad app. it works perfectly fine for iPhone however on iPad, when I connect the IBAction to thw 'Menu' button the menu should open, same way it does in iPhone, however it doesnt seem to open

THeres no crash log or error, the button just doesnt do anything

This is the code for the action but I can provide any other information that may be helpful:

```
- (IBAction)showMenu
{
    [self.sideMenuViewController presentMenuViewController];
}
```